# Menu item displying below emitting item

Tags: android, xml, menu

I want to display the menu below the emitting item, I dont know how to do that. Now it is displaying over the emitting item (material design. I use AppcompatActivity). 
[link] (google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-usage). this is what happening now. But i want it to display below the emitting item
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DwO5.jpg)

Any help is great help for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html). Read the following:

> [Menus and Popups](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Menus-and-Popups)

Comment: Its in actionbar. thanks

Comment: Its in actionbar. thanks, refer this -[link]( https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-usage). this is what happening in my case!